# How to use the the count number somewhere else in java

Tags: java

Is there anyway in which I can place count into a variable. E.g. I have Count to count the number of lines. After that I want to use the number that the count has provided, and then add this number in a variable that can be used somewhere else, e.g. to add with another number, or find an percentage or to create a pie chart using the number.

```
public void TotalCount12() throws FileNotFoundException  {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("read.txt"));
        int count = 0;
        while(file.hasNext()){
            count++;
            file.nextLine();
            }
        System.out.println(count);
        file.close();
```

I want to use the number that I will get in count, and use it somewhere else (e.g another method), but I have no idea how to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: I want to use the count as a variable in another method, or another class. I just want to know is there anyway I can do that.

Comment: Then make `count` a global variable

Comment: use it as a parameter to call the other methods create it in your class and not inside that method

Comment: Introduce a member variable as `count` with either public scope or getter for the same. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: question is not clear. If you copy whole class code it would be better to understand.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. @sundar e.g. get the count, but I want to use the count in a another method, e.g. to add the count with another number(which is count as well) but that count is in another class.

Comment: @JustMe If you're trying to access an instance variable from *another* class, provide a public getter method and retrieve the count from the instance you're referencing in that other class. The context you're using this isn't really clear, so it's difficult to provide meaningful advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I recommend that you should complete this [javatutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html) if you new to programming.

If you define it in class as a **global variable**(as an attribute of class) out of method, you can use it in every method in your class.

But if your question about to using it in everywhere of the project within different class, you can use [singleton design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern);

```
public class ClassicSingleton { 
    private static ClassicSingleton instance = null; 
    protected ClassicSingleton() {
     // Exists only to defeat instantiation. 
    } 
    public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) 
        {
            instance = new ClassicSingleton(); 
        } 
        return instance; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I would I use the Singleton design pattern with count?

Comment: Now, you got the singleton keyword and please search it on google then write your code yourself please.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Make a getter method for `count` variable.

E.g.

```
public class Test {
  private int count = 0;

  public void method1(){
    while(file.hasNext()){
        count++;
        file.nextLine();
        }
    System.out.println(count);
  }

  public void method2(){
    System.out.println(count);
  }

  public int getCount(){
    return count;
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by global variable here. It is just member variable because only Test class alone has access scope on this variable

Comment: @wns349 You are not using the term "global" correctly. This is an instance variable. It is not available "globally".

Answer (score 0):

Just return the value in the method you created:

```
public class Test {

  public int TotalCount12() throws FileNotFoundException  {
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("read.txt"));
    int count = 0;
    while(file.hasNext()) {
      count++;
      file.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println(count);
    file.close();
    return count;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    int testCount = TotalCount12();
  }

}
```